# Is there any way to reduce file size after including the QWebEngineView module?

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyinstaller, qwebengineview

My project is 55 mb after creating an exe out of it, using pyinstaller in a virtual env. I also need to use the QWebEngineView module to display a html page and some javsacript in my app, but after including the module (from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView) the file size of my exe jumps to 131 mb. Is there a workaround to reduce this 76 mb jump in file size?

Comment: Check in the dist folder and delete the new elements that were added when including QWebEngineView, if deleting that element continues to work then you can reduce its size

Comment: there is only the exe file in the dist folder, nothing else :(

Comment: Don't use the "onefile" option and you can handle that.

Comment: Yo are right, there is a translations folder in there for example (installed along with webengine) that is 22 mb and completely unnecessary for my project. On the other hand the full folder of the app in now 300+ mb. 1 step forward, 2 back. And I also have thousands of files all over the place, makes distribution much harder.

Comment: @elapidae make a simple comparison of the two folder, the one *with* the QWebEngine modules and the one *without*, then check which files you can safely remove, read how to exclude files from the documentation of pyinstaller, and finally rebuild with onefile option.